# Marshmallow message application is not opening

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to open message application from my application but I am getting ActivityNotFoundException in Marshmallow. I used the below code:

```
Intent n = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
n.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
n.putExtra("address", phone);
n.putExtra("sms_body", " ");
startActivity(n);
```

Answer (score 5):

I use this code on Android M and it works:

```
Intent n = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
n.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
n.putExtra("address", phone);
n.putExtra("sms_body", " ");
startActivity(n);
```

Comment: My answer is the same and was first :D

Comment: Work's fine in M but in L it does not carry phone number
any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I found this

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", x); 
startActivity(sendIntent);
```